# If $g(x)$ is an even function with $f(0)=0$, then how can we deduce that $f(x)$ is an odd function?

Tags: definite-integrals, even-and-odd-functions

> Let $f(x)=\int_0^x g(t)\,\mathrm dt$, where g is a non-zero even function. If $f(x + 5) = g(x)$, then $\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$, equals:$$\int_{x+5}^5g(t)\,\mathrm dt,\quad2\int_5^{x+5}g(t)\,\mathrm dt,\quad\int_5^{x+5}g(t)\,\mathrm dt,\quad5\int_{x+5}^5g(t)\,\mathrm dt?$$(One out of these four is correct)

The book gives the hint that $f(0)=0$, so, $f(x)$ is an odd function. After this information, I am able to solve the question. But I wonder how could $f(0)=0$ lead to $f(x)$ being an odd function. Seems like it has something to do with $g(x)$ being an even function, but not able to figure it out. (Though if I replace $x$ by $-x$ in the given exxpression, I am able to see that $f(x)$ is indeed odd.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative of an odd function is even. Always. This can be shown by the chain rule.

But an antiderivative of an even function may fail to be odd because of the integration constant.

E.g. $x^3$ odd implies $3x^2$ even. But $3x^2$ even does not imply $x^3+5$ odd. You need an extra condition, namely $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing $x$ by $-x$, we get, $$f(-x) = \int_0^{-x}g(t)dt.$$
With the substitution $t = -u$, we get
$$f(-x) = -\int_0^{x}g(-u)du.$$
As $g$ is even, we have that $g(-u) = g(u)$, this gives us
$$f(-x) = -\int_0^{x}g(u)du = -f(x).$$

Hence, $f$ is odd.

---

Without $g$ being even, it is not necessary that $f$ is odd, btw. Take $g(x) = x$ as a counterexample. However, you still have $f(0) = 0$ in this case. Thus, you are correct in the fact that $f(0) = 0$ does not let you conclude that $f$ is odd.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I guess the implication of the HINT is that because g(x) is even and f(0)=0, so, f(x) is odd. I am wondering how to have this direct conclusion without checking it by the method of replacing x by -x.

Comment: The definition of odd and even functions is using $x$ and $-x$. I mean, if you want to prove that a function is something, you have to prove it verifies the definition of "something", so here you can't bypass the substitution $x <-> -x$.

Comment: Actually, the word 'prove' in the title is not given by me. It's edited by someone else. I am looking for an objective approach, where I could simply tell that the function is odd just by observation. e.g. if $\sin x$ is given, we can see that it's an odd function. We don't necessarily need to replace $x$ by $-x$ to prove it. i.e. I am looking for an intuitive approach.

Comment: I have edited the title now.

Comment: In such a case, you can simply take the given result to be a "fact" much like how $\sin x$ being odd is true *by observation*. Indeed, you have the facts that: derivative of an odd (resp., even) function is even (resp., odd). For the antiderivative of an even function to be odd, you simply need the condition that $F(0) = 0$ ($F$ being the anti-derivative). (You don't require this condition for the anti-derivative of an odd function to be even.)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Yves Daoust has posted that as an answer.